# I am trying to download multiple images as a zip file related to Id using laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am trying to download multiple images as zip files related to id and I am getting all images that are available on **uploads/images** but I don't need to download all images only I want all those images that are related to id please help me how can I resolve that thanks.

**dd($files);**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "/home/developer/htdocs/yourstitchart.com/cms/public/phpCM0Yia.png"
  1 => "/home/developer/htdocs/yourstitchart.com/cms/public/phptLC57a.png"
]
```

**InboxController**

```
 public function dowloads($id)
    {
        $inboxFiles = Inbox::where('id', $id)->first()->file;

        $files = [];
        foreach ($inboxFiles as $i => $value) {
            $files[$i] = (public_path($value));
        }
        // dd($files);
 
        $zip = new \ZipArchive;
        $fileName = 'yourstitchart.zip';
        if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {

            $files = File::files(public_path('uploads/images'));
           
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($file);
                $zip->addFile($file, $relativeNameInZipFile);
            }
            $zip->close();
        }
        return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
    }
```

**HTML VIEW**

```
                   <td>
                    @if($digitizingInbox->file)
                    <a   href="{{ route('download.inbox',$digitizingInbox->id) }}"  
                       class="download btn btn-warning">Download
                    </a>
                    </a>
                    @endif
                  </td>
```

Comment: First you set up an array of files as `$files` for a particular inbox id: `$files[$i] = (...` (btw those brackets are unnecessary).  You then immediately overwrite that `$files` variable with something else, which looks like it is probably everything in uploads/images: `$files = File::...`.

Comment: please can you explain me a/c to my code thanks.